# How to avoid flickering during SSR with Next.js experimental-edge runtime and styled-component

Tags: javascript, next.js, styled-components, edge-runtime

I've set up a Next.js project using the with-styled-components example from the official [Next.js GitHub repository](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-components). My project repository is available [here](https://github.com/hcentelles/with-styled-components).

I have configured the experimental-edge runtime and added a getServerSideProps function to index.tsx. The deployed version on Vercel can be found at https://with-styled-components-gray.vercel.app/.

However, I am experiencing a flickering issue during Server-Side Rendering (SSR): initially, the content is displayed unstyled, and then, after hydration, it renders correctly. This behavior is noticeable and impacts the user experience. It's not happening without the experimental-edge config.

Is there a way to avoid this flickering issue when using the experimental-edge runtime with styled-components?

[Here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/58612) is a video of the flickering.